# lua - main.lua:18: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 12) near 'elseif'

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm coming from Java and trying to program iPad applications with lua and love2d.
I'm fairly new and I always get this error:

```
Syntax error: main.lua:18: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 12) near 'elseif'
```

This is my code:

```
function setup()
i = 0
end

function draw()
if i == 0
then
background(0, 0, 0, 0)
i = i + 1
end
elseif i == 1
then
background(255, 0, 0, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 2
then
background(0, 255, 0, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 3
then
background(0, 0, 255, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 4
then
background(255, 255, 0, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 5
then
background(255, 255, 255, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 6
then
background(0, 255, 255, 0)
i = i + 1

elseif i == 7
then
background(255, 0, 255, 0)
i = 0
end
```

What is the problem and what do I do to fix it and avoid it in the future? Thanks.

Comment: I dont have any lua experience but you may need to close all elseif's with an end

Comment: Wow, if that's how lua codes, you've convinced me not to try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have if...then...end...elseif....  The "end" doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 4):

John's answer is the right one, however since you're beginning I can't help giving you a bit of advice: it is much better to write this kind of code in a data-driven way. That means for instance re-writing your `draw()` function like this:

```
backgrounds = {
  {  0,   0,   0, 0},
  {255,   0,   0, 0},
  {  0, 255,   0, 0},
  {  0,   0, 255, 0},
  {255, 255,   0, 0},
  {255, 255, 255, 0},
  {  0, 255, 255, 0},
  {255,   0, 255, 0}
}

function draw()
  background(unpack(backgrounds[i+1]))
  i = (i+1) % 8
end
```

Have fun with Lua!